# How to get attributes per classes from Weka

Tags: weka, document-classification

I have 11 classes/categories in my data set. And for every class there are some instances assigned to it. I need to know the attributes/words that Weka extracted per category and the numeric value assigned to each attribute. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of arff file format for Weka TRAINING and CLASSIFY:

In this case I'm talking about a portion of file used in [Semeval 2014](http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2014/cdrom/pdf/SemEval2014128.pdf) competition for the Spanish...

```
@relation Task10EnglishS2014

@attribute PathLenAlign numeric

@attribute ResAlign numeric

@attribute LcAlign numeric
@attribute WupAlign numeric
@attribute Res numeric
@attribute Lc numeric
@attribute DiceSimilarityAttribute numeric
@attribute NumericEvaluation numeric
@data
1,9.5852985,3.637587,1,8.0142254,3.637587,0.75,5.000
1,9.20881283333333,3.637587,1,8.3916004,3.637587,1,5.000
0.625,2.812914,2.754695,0.761905,2.812914,2.754695,0.5,0.292893218813452,0.300
...
```

piecemeal:

```
@relation Task10EnglishS2014
```

@relation + name of the set or experiment

```
@attribute LcAlign numeric
```

@attribute + name of attribute + type of attribute

```
@data
```

from here to start the instances or vector of values ​​for each input.

This is the training set and this is used for training a model for classify new instances.
In Weka explorer we need to load this file in the Preprocess tab. Them in Classify tab you need to choose a classifier and set Cross-validation with 10 Folds and click to Start button. This will generate a model trained.

The arff classification file must have the following structure:

@relation Task10EnglishS2014

```
@attribute PathLenAlign numeric

@attribute ResAlign numeric

@attribute LcAlign numeric
@attribute WupAlign numeric
@attribute Res numeric
@attribute Lc numeric
@attribute DiceSimilarityAttribute numeric
@attribute NumericEvaluation numeric
@data
1,9.5852985,3.637587,1,8.0142254,3.637587,0.75,?
1,9.20881283333333,3.637587,1,8.3916004,3.637587,1,?
0.625,2.812914,2.754695,0.761905,2.812914,2.754695,0.5,0.292893218813452,?
...
```

The ? simbol mean that this is the value to classify.

Them you must select the option: "Supplied test set" and select the file to classify and in "Mode options..." select "Output predictions" and them right click in the model and select "Re-evaluate model on current test set".
In the right panel the results were visualized.

Comment: Thank you for your great effort and explanation. However, I already did the training step and I'm aware of the classification step. My question is to find a way to know which attributes from my data set are assigned to which class by weka (After training)